# Leave GUID null when adding entity to context

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have a `Child` model which has a property called `EmergencyContactId`. This property is a nullable GUID which points to my `Contacts` table when set (and yes, the column is set to nullable in the database). The problem is that when I call `_context.Children.Add(newChild)`, `newChild`'s `EmergencyContactId` property is automatically generated as a new GUID by EF, even though it's supposed to be null.

```
var id = newChild.EmergencyContactId;    // id is null.
_context.Children.Add(newChild);
id = newChild.EmergencyContactId;        // id is a new GUID.
```

So I tried going into my `OnModelCreating` of my database context and doing this:

```
child.Property(props => props.EmergencyContactId)
    .HasDefaultValue(null)
    .ValueGeneratedNever();
```

I thought that should fix the issue, but no such luck; the value is still auto-generated. I want EF to just leave the property alone; if it's null, it's *supposed* to be that way!

It doesn't seem like this should be so hard, but here we are. I'm at a complete loss for what to do next.

EDIT: My model

```
public class Child 
{
    // other properties


    #region EmergencyContact

    private Contact _emergencyContact = default(Contact);
    public virtual Contact EmergencyContact { get => _emergencyContact; set => _emergencyContact = value; }

    #endregion EmergencyContact


    #region EmergencyContactId

    private Guid? _emergencyContactId;
    public Guid? EmergencyContactId { get => _emergencyContactId; set => _emergencyContactId = value; }

    #endregion EmergencyContactId

    // other properties
}
```

and its configuration:

```
child.HasOne(props => props.EmergencyContact)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(props => props.EmergencyContactId)
    .HasPrincipalKey(contact => contact.Id);
```

Comment: set `EmergencyContactId` equal to `null` in model

Comment: is it somehow marked as primary key or other ? could you show how your model is defined ? as it stands, I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @viveknuna I don't follow. It already _is_ set to null on the model; EF is setting it to a new GUID.

Comment: Is this `EmergencyContactId` not a relationship id? If it is, maybe you have set the object (probably called) `EmergencyContact` to a object. When that is the case, the EmergencyContactId will be filled automatically too.

Comment: @Pac0 Updated with the relevant parts of my model and configuration.

Comment: @Max Ah, that's probably my issue! The `EmergencyContact` property is set to a new, empty instance of the `Contact` class. EDIT: Yup, setting `EmergencyContact` to null fixed it! If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @TastesLikeTurkey see answer.

Comment: @Max Great, thanks! 3 minutes until I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this `EmergencyContactId` not a relationship id? If it is, maybe you have set the object (probably called) `EmergencyContact` to an object. When that is the case, the `EmergencyContactId` will be filled automatically too with the Id of the `EmergencyContact`.

Comment: This worked. I'd assumed that with my `EmergencyContactId` set to null EF would ignore the navigation property, but apparently not.